# Powershell: Loop through existing variables to make certain ones invisible

Tags: windows, variables, powershell, foreach

My dilemma is I want to go through all my powershell variables, and for certain ones make them invisible. I'm trying to avoid writing the code for each individual variable as there are quite a few of them.

This is what I've come up with so far, and it doesn't work and hoping for a little help.

```
    $var=Get-Variable | Where-Object {($_.name -like "*label*")} | Sleect -expand Name
    foreach ($y in $var) {
    $tes="`$$y"
    $tes.Visiable=$false
    }
```

In essence, I want the "$tes" to be replaced with the actual variable name, "$labelHome" so the command would run as if I had entered "$labelHome.Visible=$false"

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't expect that code to work at all, as you have at least two typos in `Sleect` and `Visiable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Variable *label* |  %{ ($_.Value).Visible = $false }
```

Comment: Cool, the wording in the post was a bit confusing but I figured that was what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
Get-Variable *label*  | Set-Variable -Visibility Private
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. Still visible

Comment: As far as I know, that's as "invisible" as a PS variable gets.